# SublimeCodeIntel phalcon autocomplete

Tags: php, autocomplete, sublimetext3, phalcon, sublimecodeintel

[Configuring](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#configuring)

I'm creating `.codeintel/config` in project folder

```
{
    "PHP": {
        "php": 'D:\xampp\php',
        "phpExtraPaths": ["D:\xampp\phalcon-devtools-master\ide\1.2.6\Phalcon"],
        "phpConfigFile": 'php.ini'
    }
}
```

There is no autocomplete, how do I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your `project_root/.codeintel/config` file to exactly these contents (erase what you had before):

```json
{
    "PHP": {
        "php": "D:\\xampp\\php.exe",
        "phpExtraPaths": ["D:\\xampp\\phalcon-devtools-master\\ide\\1.2.6\\Phalcon"],
        "phpConfigFile": "php.ini",
        "codeintel_scan_files_in_project": true,
        "codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth": 25        
    }
}
```

Your old file had a couple of issues. First, Windows file paths should either use forward slashes `/` or double back-slashes `\\` as delimiters. Second, the file needs to be valid JSON, so you need to use double quotes everywhere. Third, I added `.exe` to the `"php"` key's value - please ensure that this is the correct location of `php.exe`. Finally, I added the last two settings to ensure that your project is being indexed, and that the indexing runs deep enough. If you have other paths that contain library files, make sure you add them to `"phpExtraPaths"` as well.

Also, please remember that SublimeCodeIntel takes some time to index everything, so autocomplete may not work right away. If things still aren't working after coding for a while and restarting once or twice, you may wish to try the suggestions in the [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#troubleshooting) section of the README, especially the one regarding deleting the database to force a fresh reindexing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, it's working without this 2 last settings. Problem is that there is no all of autocompletion, for example typing `$this->flash->` there should be `success`, `error`, `message` etc autocompletion but there is only `message`. `/**
 * @property Phalcon\Flash $flash
 */` in ControllerBase.php is solving this porblem for "flash", but it will be hard to write this commends for each service, so is there way to generate this comments automatically???

Comment: @wormk - you can try adding the last 2 settings and see if they make a difference. Also, make sure the path to PHP's standard library is included, so it can index all the various functions and options. I don't have that much experience working with PHP using this plugin (I'm a Python guy), but once everything lines up it's incredibly useful. Just keep adding paths to `"phpExtraPaths"` and folders to your project, and you should be good to go. The last 2 lines will ensure that the entire directory structure is being indexed.